# Moodle Assignment Settings - Student dialogue box

Tags: moodle

When the student uses the advanced upload of files they see a dialogue that not only allows them to upload but also they can see the files that I have uploaded on the server.

Does anyone know a way of stopping this? Is there a simple setting so that they can use a common upload dialogue box?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For Visible in moodle do you set them to Show or Hide?

Visible: Choose whether to Show or Hide the assignment from learner view. A hidden assignment will be displayed greyed out on the main course page for those with teacher, creator, manager or admin type roles but invisible to students/learners.

There is also:

Hide description before available date

Which If enabled, the assignment description is hidden before the "Available from" date. Only the assignment name is displayed.

Comment: The assignment is visible but the problem is the type of dialogue box that apprears for the student to upload their files. Instead of the standard dialogue box for uploading files, there is a big grey box that appears called "File Picker" and gives the learner the options to select "server files", "Recient files", "upload files" and "recient files".

Comment: I was wondering if i could get it to just ask tehy to upload a file?

Comment: Could you set all the things you don't want them to see under availability to unavailable? This makes it so they cannot see it at all. Only teachers / course instructors of that course can. If that's what your looking for.

Comment: Since I'm rather sure that is the only way to stop them from seeing the things. I haven't seen anything for moodle for a normal upload box without those options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't want the students to view previously uploaded files. I guess the issue is that the students deleting the old old files and re-uploading them. If this is the case, then you can disallow deleting the files from Assignment settings. For this, go to Assignment Settings and select **NO** to **Allow deleting**.

If this is not the root cause, then you cannot hide the files without a hack.